# How to run shell script on VM indefinitely?

Tags: shell, unix, cron, virtual-machine

I have a VM that I want running indefinitely. The server is always running but I want the script to keep running after I log out. How would I go about doing so? Creating a cron job?

Comment: Try "nohup command-name &"  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process

Answer (score 0):

In general the following steps are sufficient to convince most Unix shells that the process you're launching should not depend on the continued existence of the shell:

- run the command under `nohup`
- run the command in the background
- redirect all file descriptors that normally point to the terminal to other locations

So, if you want to run `command-name`, you should do it like so:

```
nohup command-name >/dev/null 2>/dev/null </dev/null &
```

This tells the process that will execute `command-name` to send all `stdout` and `stderr` to nowhere (instead of to your terminal) and also to read `stdin` from nowhere (instead of from your terminal).  Of course if you actually have locations to write to/read from, you can certainly use those instead -- anything except the terminal is fine:

```
nohup command-name >outputFile 2>errorFile <inputFile &
```

See also the answer in Petur's comment, which discusses this issue a fair bit.